# Is there any function to get all selected leaf nodes from wxtreelistctrl?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need to retrieve all selected leaf nodes from wxTreeListCtrl. Do we have any function for that? GetSelection() function gives only latest node. I would need all nodes. Or should I traverse tree and get selected leaf nodes?
Is there any better/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like `unsigned wxTreeListCtrl::GetSelections(wxTreeListItems& selections) const` ?

Comment: yes, I am building treelist project from samples of wxWidgets 3.0.3. After running that treelist project, I got a window, I selected "2-state-checkboxes" and "multiple selections" from style. then I selected some of the checkboxes of that tree. when I clicked on "Dumpselections" from operations. Now, while debugging controller is going into OnDumpSelection(). but I am not able to see proper value of "numSelected". And it is not even executing for loop from default case properly. Is it a bug or I am doing some mistake?